# Is "scant little" redundant?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases

I have seen this written (and have used it myself as well) but never really bothered to notice the meaning before. However, upon further inspection, "scant" is defined as "barely sufficient or adequate". Obviously "little" refers to something that is "small in size". Therefore, I wondered if the phrase "scant little" is considered redundant.

For example, would the phrasing in the following sentence be better as one of these?

- "She can remember scant little of the event" or
- "She can remember little of the event" or
- "She can remember scant of the event."

As for popularity, I see "little" and "scant little" used often, but rarely see "scant" alone.

Anyway, this is just my curiosity, it is of little (scant little?) importance, but any information would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I've never seen "scant" employed as a noun. And as an adjective, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scant+little+_NOUN_%2Fscant+_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28scant%20little%20_NOUN_/scant%20_NOUN_%29%3B%2Cc0) suggests that your observations are skewed: in the last 200 years it shows a peak of about 1 instance of "scant little _NOUN_" for every 900 or so instances of "scant _NOUN_"

Comment: To me, _scant_ in this usage is like _precious_: it’s an intensifier that doesn’t, perhaps, make complete logical sense, but is nonetheless used idiomatically with _little/few_ in particular. The OED does give a few slightly more useful meanings for this usage: “barely amounting to, hardly reaching” (so ‘barely amounting to little’ = even less than little) and “hardly, scarcely, barely” (so ‘scarcely a little’ = even less than a little).

Comment: Yep, as Janus says, "scant" is being used as an intensifier.  Like many intensifiers, it is technically redundant, but that redundancy serves a semantic purpose.  (And I've seen "scant" used alone quite often, as in "The teacher paid scant attention to the student in the corner.")

Comment: teeny-weeny: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teeny-weeny

Comment: any of the above comments (or perhaps all of them put together) make a much better answer than the Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as Janus says, "scant" is being used as an intensifier. Like many intensifiers, it is technically redundant, but that redundancy serves a semantic purpose. (And I've seen "scant" used alone quite often, as in "The teacher paid scant attention to the student in the corner.")

Comment: Intensifiers carry added meaning; how can they be redundant? Semantically bleached, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

If scant is being defined as inadequate it would not be redundant to use it with the word little since something that is little is not necessarily inadequate. The use of the intensifier scant, therefore, provides additional clarity to the phrase.

Consider the two situations.

A man finds hinself in the middle of a desert with a little water in his canteen.

Another man finds himself in the middle of a desert with scant little water in his canteen.

In the two situations the man with the little water appears to have amuch better chance at survival than the man with scant little water because having a little water may be just enough to survive, whereas having scant little water heavily suggests a bad end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**1997**: Congressional Review Act: Hearing Before the Subcommittee on Commercial and Administrative Law, Volume 4 By United States Congress.

> Mr. DELAHUNT. What kind of feedback have you received from either committee Chair or ranking members in terms of the receipt of these various rules?
>
> Ms. KATZEN. Scant little attention to date.
>
> Mr. DELAHUNT. Scant? Scant?
>
> Ms. KATZEN. Scant—little.
>
> Mr. DELAHUNT. OK, thank you, Ms. Katzen.

Mr. DELAHUNT seems to have noticed the same error and Ms Katzen seems to realise her mistake.

*(A glance through Ngram results shows that the US Conress Committees furnish many of the examples – I’m not sure why.)*

It seems that **scant little noun** is either a tautology or *“little noun”* is a compound noun, i.e. scant little noun can be split ***[scant little]** noun*, which is wrong, or *scant **[little noun]***, which is awkward but correct.

Compare

> A: Pass me another one of those little screws… [waits a while] … Have
> you got any?
>
> B: I’m searching through the box but they are all big ones – there are
> scant little screws.

Another, probably correct, version can be found at

**1962** Where the Heart is - Page 108 by Elizabeth Borton de Treviño

> I found him cowering miserably in his still scant little green suit .
>
> “He has caught a cold," said Maria, the cook, "and now he will die..."

In which the suit is little in size and scant = having little material.

I would avoid "scant little".

Answer (score -2):

> scant little

Is just an expression. English is full of expressions. Don't try and over-analyse or break expressions down, as you will inevitably find they make less sense than when you understand them intact. To me, "scant little" conveys similar meaning to this expression:

> just a little